# Google Analytics custom link attribution

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I've been trying to get Google's enhanced link attribution to work for a while now without success. I seem to not be the only one having issues so I want to come up with a solution to implement my own enhanced link attribution if you will. Below I have some code that I implemented to track one button on my page and it works perfect:

```
 jQuery(".submit-button").click(function(){

  ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'register',
  eventAction: 'click',
  eventLabel: 'registrations'
});
 });
```

I then set up the goals in the admin panel like so to receive the data:

Goal setup: custom

Goal Description: Event

Goal Details: Category - Equals to - register, Action - Equals to - click, Label - Equals to - registrations, Value - Equals to - (this field is set to blank)

So I have tracking for one CTA that works. I want to set the code up so it tracks any time someone clicks an a tag and records the a tags id (all my a tags have unique id's but a lot of them are just scroll links). How can I include the a tags id in the ga object shown above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event parameters can be modified to include other information that you want to send that's associated with the cilck. For example:

```
jQuery(".submit-button").click(function(){
   ga('send', {
      hitType: 'event',
      eventCategory: 'register',
      eventAction: 'click',
      eventLabel: jQuery(this).id
   });
});
```

You can do this for category, action, or label, but most likely you'd only need to specific a dynamic parameter for the label.

Comment: ok i've added the parameter like so:
  eventLabel: jQuery(this).attr('id'). Should I be targetting by .attr instead of .id like you've written above?

Comment: Also to receive the data on the GA goal setup. I've set up a new goal with category a tag clicked, action click and the label field blank. Is having a blank label field the way to intercept a dynamic value for the event label?

Comment: Yes, don't put in a label for an Event goal if it will often change.